# Load Content in Application using inbuilt chrome web browser than Default System Webview

Tags: android, webview, google-chrome-app

I am currently implementing certain features in my application as it turned out that the default web view doesn't support such features.
SO, is there any possibility that i can render my application content in inbuilt **chrome web view** inside my application rather than **android default web view** or redirecting it open **chrome** browser.
I am currently on marshmallow. i came to know about this feature implemented in the **NOUGAT** version. However, i need it on **API<23**.

Below is my code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
           // webView.setWebViewClient();

            //you can also link to a website. Example:
            //webView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
            //I have included web permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml
            //
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            //loads the WebView completely zoomed out
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            //true makes the Webview have a normal viewport such as a normal desktop browser
            //when false the webview will have a viewport constrained to it's own dimensions
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

            //override the web client to open all links in the same webview
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

            webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code I derived from [Building Web Apps in WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) but using [WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        String urlString="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miomuSGoPzIe";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString));

        intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

            Log.v("MainActivity", "NO CHROME APP INSTALLED");
            intent.setPackage(null);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the WebView in activity_main.xml

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

I have Firefox and Chrome in the Nexus phone and it opened the WebView in Chrome so I think it works.

[image]